# float vs NSDecimalNumber calculation

Tags: objective-c

I have a simple example to compare between using foat vs NSDecimalNumber :

```
    NSDecimalNumber *n1 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:33.23];
    NSDecimalNumber *n2 = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble:78.35];

    NSDecimalNumber *n3 = [n1 decimalNumberByDividingBy:n2];

    NSLog(@"decimalNumber n3 %@", n3);


    double d1 = 33.230000000000000;
    double d2 = 78.350000000000000;

    double d3 = d1/d2;

    NSLog(@"double d3 %f", d3);
```

Results :

```
 decimalNumber n3 0.42412252712188889444798978940650925335
 double d3 0.424123
```

Questions :

1. Why i have't the same results ? i think that the floating division round the results, can we do division with floats without rounding the result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is due to the differences between the precision, number of digits and base of the two types. `double` and `float` use base 2 numbers internally and have less precision, `NSDecimalNumber` uses base 10 and also has greater precision. It is similar to fractions and decimals where, for example, 1/3 and 0.333333333333333333 are not exactly the same. There are plenty of answers on SO and wider on the web, and introductory CS textbooks, that go into the finer details. HTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will revue all this :)

Comment: The issue is not rounding, it is the %f default precision. If instead you use `     `NSLog(@"double d3 %.16f", d3);` the result will be: "double d3 0.4241225271218890". Note: A double is represented in 64 bits, and has a precision of roughly 16 significant decimal digits.
An `NSDecimalNumber`: can represent a decimal integer up to 38 decimal digits long.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more of an `NSLog` issue, not a rounding issue.

Try logging `[n3 doubleValue]` instead:

```
NSLog(@"decimalNumber n3 %f", [n3 doubleValue]);
```

Comment: I don't think that it's an NSLog issue, but the doubleValue witch perhaps round the decimalNumber before converting it

Comment: %f by default rounds the value to 6 digits after the decimal point. You can try to printout more digits by changing %f in %.10f for example.

Comment: NSLog(@" d3 %.38f ", d3); prints : 0.42412252712188897030287648703961167485

Comment: Also please try to print the two NSDecimalNumbers n1 and n2 with the same technique. n1 prints: 33.22999999999998266275724745355546474457 and n2 prints: 78.34999999999999431565811391919851303101

Comment: I think that i am using the same technique. NSDecimalNumber has 38 précision digits and i am using "%.38f" to prints 38 digits of the double number. What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: nothing wrong, simply doubles are not precise enough for this use case, when converting to double you lose precision.